# How to ping an interface on shared WIFI laptop

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface, ping

I plugged my laptop on Ethernet cable with a fix IP address. I shared my WIFI card connection for open a connection to an android device. My Ethernet card device is `enp2s0` and my WIFI card device is `wlp3s0`. I dont have any problem when my network manager service is caring everything. So, I modified my IPTables rules for detect what are the TCP/UDP open needed by Android.
So I flushed my default IPTables rules like this :

```
/sbin/iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables -X
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F
/sbin/iptables -t nat -X
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -F
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -X
/sbin/iptables -t raw -F 
/sbin/iptables -t raw -X
```

And I applied these rules :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp2s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o wlp3s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i wlp3s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -o wlp3s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp2s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlp3s0 -p udp -m udp --sport 67 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 67 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlp3s0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The android device has got the IP address 10.42.0.138
When I Tried to ping it I've got these error message :

```
ping 10.42.0.138
PING 10.42.0.138 (10.42.0.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

also I can ping my WIFI card :

```
ping -c2 10.42.0.1
PING 10.42.0.1 (10.42.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.42.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms

--- 10.42.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.083/0.092/0.101/0.009 ms
```

What did I miss?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem was described here [ping_problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/372975/ping-sendmsg-operation-not-permitted-error-after-installing-iptables-on-arch-g)

in big shortcut problem is in iptables rules

And moving from comment, problem is with types in icmp. Or remove those limitation, or put similar limitation on input and output chains

Comment: It's not the same problem as the TCP traffic hasn't any problem to go out. I restrict everything to detect what' happen. And this config should work because I added the icmp open rules like `--icmp-type 8 `  and I'm trying different rules in this way

Comment: I didn't say that this is the same problem, but similar. I know that this is not TCP problem, but still this is problem with iptables. Does ping works if you do not specify icmp type both for and output chain?

Comment: Darvark You second post with your question is more productive. You're right, in punting the icmp-type 0 and 8 in the both OUTPUT and INPUT rules let the ping work Thank a lot